# Laravel 5 and AJAX dynamic select menu depending on previous select

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

Trying to create select menus that are populated by data from database. When selecting a value in the first, the contents of the second menu will be depending on which choices was made in the first.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('company', 'Company')}}
    <select selected="" class="form-control" id="company" name="university">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        @foreach($company as $key)
            <option>{{$key->Id}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @include('includes.partial', ['department' => $department])
</div>
```

Partial:

```
{{Form::label('department', 'Department')}}
    <select selected="" class="form-control" id="department" name="department">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        @foreach($department as $key)
            <option>{{$key->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setListener(); 
    });

    function setListener() {
        $('#company').change(function() {
            let value = $(this).val();
            alert(value);
            console.log(value.length);
            $.ajax({
                url:"create/" + value,
                method: "GET",
                success:function(result) {
                    $('#department').empty();
                    $('#department').html(result);
                    alert('result');
                }
            });

        });
    }
</script>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('home/package/create/{value}', 'Admin\PackageController@getContent');
```

Controller method:

```
public function getContent(Request $request, $value)
{
    $department = DB::table('department')->where('company_id', '=', $value)->get();

    return View::make('admin.package.create')
        ->with('department', $department);

}
```

When entering the url `http://localhost/exchange/exchange/public/home/package/create/10` manually in the browser for example, the page updates and the second select menu is filled with the correct values. But when doing this by selecting a value in the first menu, either nothing happens or the browser console returns an error `GET http://localhost/exchange/exchange/public/home/package/create/create/10 404 (Not Found)`

What can be wrong here? The strange thing is that the functionality works when entering the url manually.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the url the ajax request is using is flawed (you should use the full uri - without the host), or your form is missing [csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf) token.

Add the csrf tag to the html header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

add the ajax setup to somewhere, preferably globally - you should use this anyways

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Update your js request.

```
function setListener() {
    $('#company').change(function() {
        let value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
        console.log(value.length);
        $.ajax({
            url:"/exchange/exchange/public/home/package/create/" + value,
            method: "GET",
            success:function(result) {
                $('#department').empty();
                $('#department').html(result);
                alert('result');
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: on second thought, it is definitely the wrong url issue, but you should use csrf protection, so I'm not updating my answer in the hopes that you will use the extra protection ;)

Comment: Of course, there will be csrf token there, but this is for testing to get the functionality to work. Yes, figured there is something wrong with how I'm using the url.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
<script>
    $('#company').on('change', function(e) {
        console.log(e);

        let company_id = e.target.value;

        $.get('create/sub?company_id=' + company_id, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#department').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, Obj) {
                $('#department').append('<option value="'+Obj.Id+'">'+Obj.name+'</option>')
            })
        })
    });    
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function getContent(Request $request)
{
    $company_id = $request->input('company_id');
    $department = Department::where('company_id', '=', $company_id)->get();

    return response()->json($department);

}
```